# Show a menu item after site fully loaded

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I need to show a change language menu item after my Wordpress site is fully loaded. I edited the menu item `css` into my menu item:

```
.my-menu-item {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

and in my functions.php file i added as follows:

```php
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'menushow', 99 );      

function menushow() { ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        /* <![CDATA[ */
        jQuery(window).load(function() {
            // When the page has loaded
            jQuery(".my-menu-item").css("visibility", "true");
        });
        /* ]]> */
    </script>
<?php }
```

but the problem it's not working. Please help me out here...

Comment: `jQuery(".my-menu-item").css("visibility", "true");` change `true` to `visible`

Comment: How about `jQuery(".my-menu-item").show()` - even `function menushow() {  jQuery(".my-menu-item").show() }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.show()`

```
jQuery(".my-menu-item").show();
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated before you can use `.show();`, but as far as I know you have to give it the default value `display: none;` to work.

The Style `visibility: true;` does not exist, try `visibility: visible;` [More information here!](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
jQuery(window).load(function($) {
```

instead of

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
```

If it doesn't work, try to make a separate script file, put your code into it and attach that script file to your theme.